# Entering Dates into mysql database using sql INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, html, date, variables

A better suggestion on how to approach this then what I have done so far would be appreciated. Right now the dates have to be entered in the correct format year-month-day. Is there a way to automate this task more, with drop downs, just not sure how you would combine the information from the drop downs to submit to one field with my sql INSERT INTO command. This is what it looks like for a quick visual 
[site](http://www.andcreate.com/news/insert.php)

Here is an example of my code below.

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$entry = $_POST['entry'];





if(($date !="") && ($title !="") && ($entry !="")) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO news (date,title,entry)VALUES(
\"$date\",
\"$title\",
\"$entry\"
)";

$results = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

}
?>







<form name="formS" method="post" action="insert.php">
<p>
Date:<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />

</p>

<p>
Title<input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
</p>
<p>
Entry:<textarea name ="entry"  ></textarea>
</p>

<p>
Submit:<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</p>


</form>
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but I think you should read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection :)

Comment: Not much to fear from SQL injection with an insert, since you can't run multiple queries in one statement by default (I think it's PHP that locks this out), BUT...  +1 for bringing it up, as it is an important overall consideration :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One free-form date input field can be fine, depending on your needs.  This will give people a lot of flexibility in how they enter a date.  For instance, this will work if someone enters "Yesterday" or "7 days ago".

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

Demo:

```
$date_expressions = array(
    "yesterday",
    "tomorrow",
    "7 days ago",
    "next year",
    "last month",
    "10 jan 08"
);

date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($date_expressions as $date_expression) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_expression));
    echo "{$date_expression} = {$date}\n";
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Output (executed on 10-9-2009):

```
yesterday = 2009-10-08
tomorrow = 2009-10-10
7 days ago = 2009-10-02
next year = 2010-10-09
last month = 2009-09-09
10 jan 08 = 2008-01-10
```

Comment: This is great! how would I go about reversing this for example fetching the row 'date' from my table and having it output "tomorrow today 7 days ago" etc... with a echo statement?

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time

Answer (score 0):

You can simply accept the date as multiple drop down boxes and then combine them before inputting it in the database

```
$date = $_POST['dateyear']."-".$_POST['datemonth']."-".$_POST['dateday'];
```

Comment: Also, make sure you sanitize/filter the input.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was trying to figure out. What does sanatize/filter mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple inputs for the date, you can combine it like this:

```
$date = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $_POST['date_year'], $_POST['date_month'], $_POST['date_day']);
```